# Dedicated hosting : How to install the PHP?

Tags: php, centos, dedicated-server

Due to some insufficient memory limit we bought a dedicated server. We installed most of the things by using putty. But we are unable to install the PHP package. If we try to install it's saying package is not available . Could any one can suggest me how i can install this? we purchased cent os v5.

**Error Message :**

```
root@vs-bgiger [/]# yum install php-common php-gd php-mcrypt php-pear php-pecl-memcache php-mhash php-mysql php-xml                          Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.internode.on.net
 * extras: mirror.internode.on.net
 * updates: mirror.optus.net
base                                                                                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package php-common available.
No package php-gd available.
No package php-mcrypt available.
No package php-pear available.
No package php-pecl-memcache available.
No package php-mhash available.
No package php-mysql available.
No package php-xml available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: please check it back.. Posted the error report (Coming from putty).

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
yum search php
```

What are the results?

If you still don't have any php results you can add the rpmforge and EPEL repositories and search again.